# Obtaining a list of all fiscal years between two dates

Tags: r

A federal fiscal year goes from **October 1** - **September 30** and is identified by the year of the ending date. For example, **FY20** goes from **October 1, 2019 - September 30, 2020**.

Given a data frame with a unique ID, a start date, and an end date, how can I obtain a long table containing all fiscal years between those dates without having to write a calculation to manually validate each fiscal year?

```
ID   START_DT   END_DT
1    08/15/17   08/15/19 
2    08/15/17   08/15/18
```

Reproducible example:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2),
           start_dt = c(as.Date("2017-08-15"), as.Date("2017-08-15")),
           end_dt = c(as.Date("2019-08-15"), as.Date("2018-08-15")))
```

Desired end result:

```
ID  FY
1   17
1   18
1   19
2   17
2   18
```

**Edit: Possible Solution**

Here is one solution inspired by Jon Spring's suggestion:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2),
           start_dt = c(as.Date("2017-08-15"), as.Date("2017-08-15")),
           end_dt = c(as.Date("2019-08-15"), as.Date("2018-08-15")))

dat_fy <- data.frame(date_seq = seq(from = min(dat$start_dt), 
                                    to = max(dat$end_dt), 
                                    by = 1)) %>% 
  mutate(fy = ifelse(month(date_seq) <= 9, 
                     year(date_seq), 
                     year(date_seq) + 1))

dat %>% 
  full_join(dat_fy, by = character()) %>% 
  filter(date_seq >= start_dt & date_seq <= end_dt) %>% 
  distinct(id, fy)
```

Comment: This sounds like a good situation for using a non-equi join, which can applied using `data.table`, `sqldf`, or `fuzzyjoin`. First create a list of FY-end dates, then join to it conditional on start being earlier and end being later than those dates.

Comment: thanks so much. i ended up using a join-based solution with a lookup table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function, `fyear`, that converts a date to a fiscal year by converting to yearqtr class and adding 1/4 which pushes Oct/Nov/Dec to the next calendar year so that the calendar year of that is the required fiscal year.  Finally apply it to each row by grouping by `id`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

fyear <- function(...) as.integer(as.yearqtr(...) + 1/4)

dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_modify(~ data.frame(fyear = fyear(.$start_dt):fyear(.$end_dt) %% 100)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id fyear
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    17
2     1    18
3     1    19
4     2    17
5     2    18
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` approach using a lookup-table with fiscal years

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(dat)
dat.fiscal <- data.table( start = seq(as.Date("2000-10-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by = "1 year"),
                          end   = seq(as.Date("2001-09-30"), as.Date("2021-09-30"), by = "1 year"))
dat.fiscal[, fy := lubridate::year(end)]
setkey(dat, start_dt, end_dt)
setkey(dat.fiscal, start, end)

foverlaps(dat, dat.fiscal)
#         start        end   fy id   start_dt     end_dt
# 1: 2016-10-01 2017-09-30 2017  2 2017-08-15 2018-08-15
# 2: 2017-10-01 2018-09-30 2018  2 2017-08-15 2018-08-15
# 3: 2016-10-01 2017-09-30 2017  1 2017-08-15 2019-08-15
# 4: 2017-10-01 2018-09-30 2018  1 2017-08-15 2019-08-15
# 5: 2018-10-01 2019-09-30 2019  1 2017-08-15 2019-08-15
```